# promiscuous mode with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 AGN wireless card

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time, googling, reading and trying with no help.
I have laptop with Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 AGN wireless card which suppose to support promiscuous mode (monitor mode) so I can capture traffic from the router using wireshark/ethereal or any network packets sniffer software.

I'm running Win7 home premium and can't find how to enable this mode. at the current I'm able to capture only my own traffic.
I have the Intel PROSET/Wireless software for the home user version fully installed but can't find the promiscuous mode option there neither.

can anyone give me advice how to solve this issue?
Many thanks!

Comment: are you picking up surrounding traffic on your laptop wireless NIC? I have intel centrino advanced-n 6235 and can't pick anything else up but my own traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the NetMon. In Netmon, you can click on the desired adapter and click promiscuous mode. If you are able to see the checkbox and click it then your card has the capability to run to Promiscuous mode..

Hope it works..

Happy Sniffing ..

Answer (score 1):

If i remember right you need the winPCAP drivers.
http://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm

Comment: Already installed... but still, can't find how to turn promiscuous mode on.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Wire shark  it will ask if you want install the winPCAP drivers, when you fire up wireshark you will have the ability to turn on "promiscuous mode" in wire shark. there is no button that says promiscuous mode. you will choose to monitor a Microsoft service that turns on promiscuous more which allows you to monitor the network

Comment: great! your the man! thanks a lot, it's been a long time I couldn't find aproproate solution, I didn't digged yet too much but it's seems to be working. 10x

Answer (score 0):

Promiscuous mode is not the same as monitor mode (RFMON).

- **Promiscuous Mode:**

Only possible in a wireless or wired network that you have associated with.
In promiscuous mode, you can indeed monitor the network and see traffic meant for others, but only if you have authenticated to the access point.  It is this mode that enables tools like WinPCAP and dependent technologies (Firesheep and Wireshark, for example) to work.

- **Monitor Mode (RFMON)**

Monitor Mode is one of six modes specified by the 802.11 specification set (The others are Master, Repeater, Managed, Ad-hoc, Mesh). If a wireless adapter is set to Monitor mode, it is able to recieve traffic from wireless networks it is not associated with.

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode

http://lazysolutions.blogspot.com/2008/10/difference-promiscuous-vs-monitor-mode.html